# Bash scripting - escape characters in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to execute a word search in my directory where I look into all text files, and try to find words that have a length of 14.

```
$ ls *.txt | & grep -o -w '\w\{14,14\}'
```

This works as intended when I run it in a command line.

Now I want to run this same exact command but in a .sh file

In my file, I have this:

```
eval $("ls *.txt | & grep -o -w '\w\{14,14\}'")
```

I then get this error:

test.sh: line 1: ls *.txt | & grep -o -w '\w{14,14}': command not found

Is the problem that I have escape characters in my text? How can I get it so that when I run my .sh file, I get the same output as if I ran it on the command line?

Comment: Why do you think you need the `eval` line? Your script should contain the *exact same thing* you run on the command line; no `eval`, no extra quotes.

Comment: (By the way, `|&` is a single token; the `|` and `&` shouldn't be separated by whitespace -- and make sure your shell is `#!/bin/bash` or similar, as it's bash-only syntax).

Comment: What is the point of eval'ing a command in a subshell?

Comment: ...also, are you looking for *filenames* of that length? If so, there's no need for `ls` *or* `grep`; you can do such a search with the shell alone.

Comment: Your code does not match your description.  It would really help if you show examples of input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think they are trying to find the words inside files (re: "I am trying to execute a word search in my directory where I look into all text files, and try to find words that have a length of 14."), although the command doesn't reflect that whatsoever.

Comment: @l'L'l That is what I thought at first but note that the OP also wrote that the command "works as intended when I run it in a command line."  The OP needs to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `eval` something to put it in a shell script. `eval` is evil, and should be avoided like the plague (as in, only use if you have invented the antidote yourself). Your statement could be changed to simply `grep -o -w '\w\{14,14\}' *.txt` and chucked verbatim into a script file.

An excellent web site to learn both the fundamentals and the subtleties of Bash scripting is [Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/).

Comment: Gah, thanks for the advice. I think I was too much in the weeds when learning how to make shell scripts.